# Django url redirect in form action

Tags: django, django-urls

I have tried a lot of different things, but I cannot get my action to redirect once my form saves.

My loans_form.html:

```
<form action="{% url loans %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit loan request" /></p>
</form>
```

And my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import LoanListView, LoanCreateView

urlpatterns =[
    path('', LoanListView.as_view(), name='loans'),
    path('create', LoanCreateView.as_view(), name='create')
]
```

Comment: You here post to your `LoanListView`, *not* to your `LoanCreateView`, given `LoanListView` is a `ListView`, it thus does not care about the form at all.

Answer (score 2):

Given `LoanListView` is a `ListView` and `LoanCreateView` is a `CreateView`, you should post to the `LoanCreateView`, since that is the view that will parse the form, and make the correct actions, so you should write:

```
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

In the `LoanCreateView`, you can the specify to which view you want to redirect in case the handling was successful, by specifying the `success_url` attribute. If you want to specify the name of a view, then typically [**`reverse_lazy`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy), can help you with that:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class LoanCreateView(CreateView):
    # ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('loans')
```

Comment: If I'm using a modelform do I need to provide an aciton?

Comment: @Davtho1983: of course, since HTML does not know anything about that form. A form is only used to render to HTML, but the HTML needs to know to which endpoint it has to send the data evidently.